# unable to update to magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, mageplaza

I am trying to upgrade Magento from 2.3.3 to 2.3.6 but I am getting the below error and the update is not happening.

[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-image-optimizer.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
sh: 1: git: not found

I have deleted this extension even though the composer is still trying to download the module and I cleared the cache of the composer using the below commands.

// Clear cache
composer clearcache
// OR
composer clear-cache

// Completely remove the cache directory
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer

still, I am getting the above issue only.

for reference please find the attached images.
[image]

Comment: check your dependencies from other magepla$a modules, perhaps image-optimizer is required by one of them.

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-image-optimizer/issues/1

Comment: This extension does not belong to the given username and password key which is specified in auth.json. https://mage2.pro/t/topic/743 check this you will get idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had installed image optimiser from GitHub after few days later they removed the complete repository from GitHub sfter that we are trying to update Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.6. Here we are facing the problem with image optimiser extension. We had removed extension from our application even though still it is looking for image optimiser extension update from GitHub.
So We have to remove that image optimiser extension from composer.json in root folder of the application